# Copy rows on condition to another Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel file with 1 Worksheet. In that Worksheet there is data in 1 column and 250,000 rows.

I want to select rows which contain a specific string say "workspace" in that 1 column. So for example if cell A4 has value "D:\abc\workspace-PB\test" then I want to select 4th row.

And I want to copy the selected rows to another Worksheet in the same Excel file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click *Home > Find & Select > Find*. In the dialog box input the text that you need in the dropdown list.
2. Click the *Find All* button and all the matching cells will be listed. In case you have a lot of rows, it could take a long time.
3. Press **Ctrl + A** to select all the values in the box and click *Close*. Again, be patient, because it could take a long time.
4. Copy and paste on other worksheet.